# Flutter - passing an instance of a class, or using multiple instances?

Tags: flutter

Question for Flutter users.
I have a class which holds a number of static values regarding a project. These values need to be accessible in various widgets.

Is it more efficient to create one instance of that class in the main.dart file, and pass it's pointer through to all the widgets that need it, or should each widget create it's own instance of the class? Given that the parameters within the class will never change.

I suspect both is fine (especially when  there are only 20 or so parameters), but I want to select the more efficient approach.

Comment: Is the class contains only static values?

Comment: how about making the class static to access values without the instance?

Comment: Yes, all static values.

Comment: so, if I set every parameter in settings to static const, then is if more efficient to just reference the class directly, eg ProjectSettings().mainMenuItems ? If so, should I therefore pass in the same reference of "ProjectSettings()" to each widget, or have them each reference "ProjectSettings()" themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You can use get_it library to access singleton object anywhere in the project very easily.

It is called service locator class. Initialise it in the main(). Then create object once but access or update anywhere else.

I am using this for settings data across all pages.
For example I have created SettingsData class, inside there is a Map<String,String> to hold all project related data for which state to be maintained after closing and opening again.

So this _data object is accessed anywhere using get_it library. See example in pub.dev, very straight forward.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).